# Three r71 SubdivisionModifier not included

Tags: three.js

I cant find THREE.SubdivisionModifier in r71, r60 works fine.

There are some changes or it is totaly removed?

Is there any alternative to to this?
http://client.kadrmasconcepts.com/blog_examples/html5-webgl-subdivision/

Comment: it is in examples/js/modifiers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it is not part of the build, but you can find it in the examples folder: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/modifiers/SubdivisionModifier.js

So you have to download this file, include in your project, and then you can use SubdivisionModifier again.